# cannot read image in jar file: javafx

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, jar

when I build a jar file an run it, i can't see the image. 
In Eclipse it is working all good.

The Image should be a Button

```
<effect>
    <ImageInput>
       <source>
          <Image url="file:./images/record_by_felickzs.PNG" />
       </source>
    </ImageInput>
</effect>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is because on eclipse the image is not packed so it is accessible the way you are doing it, however when you export a jar file the image is packed and you can not access file inside the jar that way,,, use relative path instead:

```
<effect>
    <ImageInput>
       <source>
          <Image url="@../../images/record_by_felickzs.PNG" />
       </source>
    </ImageInput>
 </effect>
```

edit : replace PNG with png

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer but I have still the same problem

Comment: try .png instead of .PNG please

Comment: this makes no different

Comment: then we'll have to check the contents of your jar file